# How to cast an array of abstract classes by an array of interfaces

Tags: java, sorting, user-interface, casting, abstract

I have a small question.
Suppose we have `Person` which is an interface and `Student` which is an abstract class and `UnderGrad` which is a normal class that implements `Person` and extends `Student`.

Then, in another class, there is an array of students, i.e. `Student[]`, that contains only `UnderGrad` objects.

And in that class, there is a static method that takes `Person[]` as a parameter and sorts them by their age.

```java
public static sortStudents(Person[] people) {
    // It sorts them 
}
```

How could I cast the array `Student[]`, which is full of `UnderGrad`s, into a `Person[]` array which is implemented by `UnderGrad`?

Comment: One way is to make your `Student` class implement `Person` instead of `Undergrad`.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class can implement an interface without even declaring any of the interface methods. Then any class that extends the abstract class automatically also implements the interface. For example, class [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) implements interface `TableModel` but does not include method `getRowCount()`. Hence any class that extends `AbstractTableModel` automatically also implements interface `TableModel` and must therefore implement method `getRowCount()`.

So all you need to do is make [abstract] class `Student` implement interface person and have class `UnderGrad` implement the methods of `Person`, which I understand you have already done, anyway.

```java
public interface Person { }

public abstract class Student implements Person {
    // No need to include any methods from 'Person'
}

public class UnderGrad extends Student {
    // Here you must implement methods of 'Person'
}
```

If your `sortStudents()` method only calls methods of interface `Person` then no need for any casts.